# Why are contracts in Ethereum Blockchain called as 'Smart Contracts'?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

We write smart contracts in ethereum blockchain. How did contracts get its name as Smart Contracts? Why are they called as Smart Contracts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn’t seem to be about programming

Comment: It would probably be welcome over at ethereum.stackexchange.com, though.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts are self-executing, self-enforcing contracts.Basically they are code residing on ethereum that get executed when specific condition are met.They are governed by the explicit terms and conditions laid out within them. These virtual agreements can facilitate the exchange of money, content, shares, property, or anything of value.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the Smart contract name was formed:

Nick Szabo, an American computer scientist who invented a virtual currency called "Bit Gold" in 1998, defined smart contracts as computerized transaction protocols that execute terms of a contract.

For more information check this resource: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/smart-contracts.asp